# Show whole div with jquery filter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have this code which only returns text values from #myDIV. That div has a section inside which contains multiple divs (product list) with images, texts and image captions. My filter works with both caption and text (that's what i wanted) but it only returns the text values. The caption ones return as an empty result and the images are not shown at all. I want to return all 3 (text/caption/image).

P.S Section contains multiple "container px-3" divs

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="myDIV">
  <section class="extShop featuresLink cid-rZqXvAXY2V" id="extShop2-aj">
    <div class="container px-3">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card-img"><img src="assets/images/brunello-di-montalcino-poggio-alle-mura-2009docg-239x555.jpg" alt="" title="">
            </div>
            <div class="card-box align-left">
              <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-4 pb-2">Red Wines Banfi</p>
              <h4 class="card-title mbr-fonts-style display-7"><br><br>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mbr-popup-7g" class="text-danger"></a><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mbr-popup-8l" class="text-danger">Brunello di Montalcino Poggio alle Mura 2009DOCG</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why use a filter and not return anything? Sounds like you need a .each or to return something and then do an each

Comment: *code which only returns text values* - I think we have a different idea of what "returns text values" means - it looks like you're doing a text-search or text-filter

Comment: Change `$(this).text()` to `$(this).html()` - not sure exactly what you want but that will solve the issue described - eg you'll be able to enter "img" to filter your results to those with `<img>` tags

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you, the .html seems to work better than the .text